# Bare minimum Angular JS module dependency

Tags: angularjs

I am a AngularJS noob. Could anyone tell me what is the bare minimum requirement for a module to allow other modules to depend on it.

The code

```
angular.module('test',[]);
angular.module('test2',[test]);
```

gives error.

I have also tried switching the statements for somewhere I read that module are read in the reverse order!!.

Could someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, asking a noob question garnered negative reputation!!.

This is neither non-reproduce-able nor a typographical error.  Specially given that most other languages don't use strings for referenced packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependency name is an array of string

Like this

```
angular.module('test2',['test']);
```